# Active CustomLayout slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

How can I get the index number of the active/current CustomLayout that is being displayed in the Slide Master view?

I want to be able to have the user change the current CustomLayout's name.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Name to return or set the name of the currently selected layout. If the user's selected multiple layouts, it seems that PPT will rename only the first one.

Comment: I tried:Sub CustomLayoutName()
Debug.Print ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts.item.Name
End Sub

Comment: Thanks @SteveRindsberg! Worked like a charm. Brax, you didn't need to downgrade my question when it was evident I was getting nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by @steveRindsberg in the comments worked great:

```
ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Name
```